# Get font and size of an acroform field

Tags: pdfclown

I need to get access to the font style and size of an acroform text field.  I have access to the `Field` object via [pdfclown](http://www.stefanochizzolini.it/en/projects/clown/) but can't work out how to access the font. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Java or C# version of PdfClown? Default appearance font and size or actual appearance?

Comment: Java.  I want the actual appearance of the control.  The reason is that I use a template with acroforms and populate the fields from java code.  I am going to delete the controls from the final generated file and replace it with a text of the same appearance because the default PDF readers on iPhone and Android don't display acroforms at all.  Basically I want to flatten the PDF completely removing all acroform controls from the generated file but retaining their values.

Comment: ok, in that case you should simply use the normal appearance of the field, transform it into an XObject, and reference that XObject from the content stream. You don't need to know the details at all. I'm not too proficient in PdfClown, so I'll have to look up how to do that. Probably won't have the time during this weekend.

Comment: Ok, so the original PDF Clown developer was faster... ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm glad to announce you that today I committed to the [PDF Clown's repository](http://sourceforge.net/p/clown/code/) *the fully-functional implementation of the **FormFlattener***, both on the current branch ([0.1.2-Fix](http://sourceforge.net/p/clown/code/HEAD/tree/branches/0.1.2-Fix), [rev 129](http://sourceforge.net/p/clown/code/129/), [131](http://sourceforge.net/p/clown/code/131/), [133](http://sourceforge.net/p/clown/code/133/)) and on [trunk](http://sourceforge.net/p/clown/code/HEAD/tree/trunk) ([rev 130](http://sourceforge.net/p/clown/code/130/), [132](http://sourceforge.net/p/clown/code/132/), [134](http://sourceforge.net/p/clown/code/134/)): I suggest you to download directly from that SVN repo to get the latest features & fixes.

Otherwise, in case you stick with the published release (0.1.2.0), here it is the relevant code (again, I recommend the committed version as it's more refined). First of all, we need some adjustment:

1) in **XObject**.java replace the `wrap` method:

```
public static XObject wrap(
  PdfDirectObject baseObject
  )
{
  if(baseObject == null)
    return null;

  PdfName subtype = (PdfName)((PdfStream)baseObject.resolve()).getHeader().get(PdfName.Subtype);
  if(PdfName.Form.equals(subtype))
    return FormXObject.wrap(baseObject);
  else if(PdfName.Image.equals(subtype))
    return ImageXObject.wrap(baseObject);
  else
    return null;
}
```

2) in **FormXObject**.java replace the `wrap` method:

```
public static FormXObject wrap(
  PdfDirectObject baseObject
  )
{
  if(baseObject == null)
    return null;

  PdfDictionary header = ((PdfStream)PdfObject.resolve(baseObject)).getHeader();
  PdfName subtype = (PdfName)header.get(PdfName.Subtype);
  /*
    NOTE: Sometimes the form stream's header misses the mandatory Subtype entry; therefore, here
    we force integrity for convenience (otherwise, content resource allocation may fail, for 
    example in case of Acroform flattening).
  */
  if(subtype == null && header.containsKey(PdfName.BBox))
  {header.put(PdfName.Subtype, PdfName.Form);}
  else if(!subtype.equals(PdfName.Form))
    return null;

  return new FormXObject(baseObject);
}
```

Then we can define the actual form flattener:

3) add **FormFlattener**.java to org.pdfclown.tools package:

```
package org.pdfclown.tools;

import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.util.EnumSet;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.pdfclown.documents.Document;
import org.pdfclown.documents.Page;
import org.pdfclown.documents.PageAnnotations;
import org.pdfclown.documents.contents.xObjects.FormXObject;
import org.pdfclown.documents.interaction.annotations.Annotation.FlagsEnum;
import org.pdfclown.documents.interaction.annotations.Widget;
import org.pdfclown.documents.interaction.forms.Field;
import org.pdfclown.documents.interaction.forms.Fields;
import org.pdfclown.documents.interaction.forms.Form;
import org.pdfclown.objects.PdfArray;
import org.pdfclown.objects.PdfDictionary;
import org.pdfclown.objects.PdfDirectObject;
import org.pdfclown.objects.PdfName;
import org.pdfclown.objects.PdfObjectWrapper;
import org.pdfclown.objects.PdfReference;
import org.pdfclown.tools.PageStamper;
import org.pdfclown.util.math.geom.Dimension;

public class FormFlattener
{
  private boolean hiddenRendered;
  private boolean nonPrintableRendered;

  /**
    Replaces the Acroform fields with their corresponding graphics representation.

    @param document Document to flatten.
  */
  public void flatten(
    Document document
    )
  {
    Map<PdfDirectObject,PageStamper> pageStampers = new HashMap<PdfDirectObject,PageStamper>();
    Form form = document.getForm();
    Fields formFields = form.getFields();
    for(Field field : formFields.values())
    {
      for(Widget widget : field.getWidgets())
      {
        Page widgetPage = widget.getPage();
        EnumSet<FlagsEnum> flags = widget.getFlags();
        // Is the widget to be rendered?
        if((!flags.contains(FlagsEnum.Hidden) || hiddenRendered)
          && (flags.contains(FlagsEnum.Print) || nonPrintableRendered))
        {
          // Stamping the current state appearance of the widget...
          PdfName widgetCurrentState = (PdfName)widget.getBaseDataObject().get(PdfName.AS);
          FormXObject widgetCurrentAppearance = widget.getAppearance().getNormal().get(widgetCurrentState);
          if(widgetCurrentAppearance != null)
          {
            PageStamper widgetStamper = pageStampers.get(widgetPage.getBaseObject());
            if(widgetStamper == null)
            {pageStampers.put(widgetPage.getBaseObject(), widgetStamper = new PageStamper(widgetPage));}

            Rectangle2D widgetBox = widget.getBox();
            widgetStamper.getForeground().showXObject(widgetCurrentAppearance, new Point2D.Double(widgetBox.getX(), widgetBox.getY()), new Dimension(widgetBox.getWidth(), widgetBox.getHeight()));
          }
        }

        // Removing the widget from the page annotations...
        PageAnnotations widgetPageAnnotations = widgetPage.getAnnotations();
        widgetPageAnnotations.remove(widget);
        if(widgetPageAnnotations.isEmpty())
        {
          widgetPage.getBaseDataObject().put(PdfName.Annots, null);
          widgetPageAnnotations.delete();
        }

        // Removing the field references relating the widget...
        PdfDictionary fieldPartDictionary = widget.getBaseDataObject();
        while (fieldPartDictionary != null)
        {
          PdfDictionary parentFieldPartDictionary = (PdfDictionary)fieldPartDictionary.resolve(PdfName.Parent);

          PdfArray kidsArray;
          if(parentFieldPartDictionary != null)
          {kidsArray = (PdfArray)parentFieldPartDictionary.resolve(PdfName.Kids);}
          else
          {kidsArray = formFields.getBaseDataObject();}

          kidsArray.remove(fieldPartDictionary.getReference());
          fieldPartDictionary.getReference().delete();

          if(!kidsArray.isEmpty())
            break;

          fieldPartDictionary = parentFieldPartDictionary;
        }
      }
    }
    if(formFields.isEmpty())
    {
      // Removing the Acroform root...
      document.setForm(null);
      form.delete();
    }
    for(PageStamper pageStamper : pageStampers.values())
    {pageStamper.flush();}
  }

  /**
    Gets whether hidden fields have to be rendered.
  */
  public boolean isHiddenRendered(
    )
  {return hiddenRendered;}

  /**
    Gets whether non-printable fields have to be rendered.
  */
  public boolean isNonPrintableRendered(
    )
  {return nonPrintableRendered;}

  /**
    @see #isHiddenRendered()
  */
  public FormFlattener setHiddenRendered(
    boolean value
    )
  {
    hiddenRendered = value;
    return this;
  }

  /**
    @see #isNonPrintableRendered()
  */
  public FormFlattener setNonPrintableRendered(
    boolean value
    )
  {
    nonPrintableRendered = value;
    return this;
  }
}
```

And this is an example using it:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.pdfclown.documents.Document;
import org.pdfclown.files.File;
import org.pdfclown.tools.FormFlattener;

File file = null;
try
{
  // 1. Opening the PDF file...
  {
    try
    {file = new File(myFilePath);}
    catch(Exception e)
    {throw new RuntimeException(myFilePath + " file access error.",e);}
  }
  Document document = file.getDocument();

  // 2. Flatten the form!
  FormFlattener formFlattener = new FormFlattener();
  formFlattener.flatten(document);

  // 3. Serialize the PDF file!
  try
  {file.save(SerializationModeEnum.Standard);}
  catch(Exception e)
  {
    System.out.println("File writing failed: " + e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
finally
{
  // 4. Closing the PDF file...
  if(file != null)
  {
    try
    {file.close();}
    catch(IOException e)
    {/* NOOP */}
  }
}
```

To keep yourself up-to-date with the activity about the project, you can follow PDF Clown on its site ([pdfclown.org](http://pdfclown.org/)) and through its twitter stream (https://twitter.com/pdfclown).

Comment: Looks good. Two remarks, though: **A** You add only the appearances for widgets with `!flags.contains(FlagsEnum.Hidden) && flags.contains(FlagsEnum.Print)`; I would allow the caller to choose whether or not hidden or non-printing fields should have their appearances added. **B** It looks like you don't visualize fields without appearances. Especially if the PDF has **/NeedAppearances true**, the code should try and create appearances where needed.

Comment: I agree with both of your considerations, thanks! I'm gonna add an option to unlock hidden and non-printable fields (it will be upon the users to honour the format policies avoiding it on production environments). Appearance synthesization is important for high-quality rendering, but I would prefer to work on actual specimens of fields without appearance in order to test real cases: please don't hesitate to report me files containing such fields, thank you!

Comment: I have none at my hands now. If I happen to come across one, I'll point you towards it.

Comment: @StefanoChizzolini awesome thanks.  Can confirm that I can now see the form values on iPhone and Android.

Answer (score -1):

```
public void flatten(Document document) {
    Map<Page, PageStamper> pageStampers = new HashMap<Page, PageStamper>();
    Form form = document.getForm();
    Fields formFields = form.getFields();
    for (Field field : formFields.values()) {
        for (Widget widget : field.getWidgets()) {
            Page widgetPage = widget.getPage();             
            PageStamper widgetStamper = pageStampers.get(widgetPage);
            if (widgetStamper == null) {
                pageStampers.put(widgetPage,widgetStamper = new PageStamper(widgetPage));
            }
            PrimitiveComposer composer = widgetStamper.getForeground();
            composer.setFont(new StandardType1Font(document,StandardType1Font.FamilyEnum.Courier, false, false), 7);                                    
            composer.showText(field.getName(), new Point2D.Double(widget.getBox().getX()+3, widget.getBox().getY()+3));

        }
        field.delete();
    }
    if (formFields.isEmpty()) {
        // Removing the form root...
        document.setForm(null);
        form.delete();
    }
    for (PageStamper pageStamper : pageStampers.values()) {
        pageStamper.flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: Now Fields are completely removed from the document

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. E.g. in which way it is an improvement compared to @Stefano's one.

Comment: Howard, please let me know the goal of your answer (as it was posted much later than mine, I expect you were addressing some deficiency in my solution and I would appreciate any improvement proposal). thanks!